# Is there a LGPL/Apache/BSD Python library for rendering modern HTML and Flash with a transparent background on Windows,Mac,Linux?

Tags: python, webkit, widget, alphablending, gecko

I'm looking for a Python library that's suitable, with DOM access too.
I don't mind if the flash transparency doesn't carry over. PyQT's license isn't compatible with the project, and PySide isn't compiled cross-platform yet.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the [pyside](http://www.pyside.org/) project now provides LGPL 2.1 python bindings for Qt.

The first public release was on August 18th.  It is being developed with support from Nokia.

According to the [release announcement](http://www.pyside.org/2009/08/pyside-has-been-released/) the bindings are initially focused on Linux/X11 but expect to support all Qt supported platforms eventually.

Comment: That's very interesting. So at some point if it can be made to compile for Mac and Windows it could be an option. Well worth investigating. For now the definitive answer remains unknown to me.